# Most efficient way to save RGB-Color

Tags: performance, rgb, pseudocode, rgba

I have a rather simple question:
If I want to save a Color in the RGB spectrum, then what would be the most efficient way for saving it in the memory? (I am excluding wrapper classes, because that would depend on the language)

For example in Pseudo-Code:

```
int r = 255;
int g = 255;
int b = 255;
```

and

```
string rgb = "#FFFFFF";
```

are two ways to describe a rgb-value, but also there would be more space reserved then needed. I want to know if there is a "best" way to do this.

In my opinion, it may be the `char` datatype, but you would need three of them and how would you save them efficient then?

Comment: Err, probably depends on your language and also if you mean in memory or on disk...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question. If it depends on the language, then you say there is no "best" way?

Comment: The problem got to my by merging two components of a project. The one side described rgb as floats from 0 to 1 and the other side used integers from 0 to 255. (It was a java project) I just thought maybe there would be a generic solution or at least something like that to this kind of problem. I guess that this occurs not only with rgb values.

Comment: Depends what you mean by efficient, because it depends on how you plan to use it. Also depends on the language.

Comment: I have to send the color values across the net, so i want as less traffic as possible. Since it depends on the language i may say that i am working with libGDX, so it is Java-development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it might not be the most efficient way, storing all three 8 bit values in one int and if necessary using the remaining 8 bits for the alpha is a standard way to do this. For example (In C-like code):

```
int convert(int r, int g, int b, int a)
{
    return (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a;
}

int getR(int rgba)
{
    return (rgba >> 24) & 0xFF;
}
```

To get the other values out, simply replace the shift by 24 with 16 for green, 8 for blue, 0 for alpha.

Storing three chars would also work just fine. A string uses much more memory than needed. But really, how many colors are you storing? Does your application use so many that the storage space is significant? If not, probably no need to worry about it.

Comment: I worked on an application to control colored lightning of a bridge in town and every user can insert his desired color, so it depends on the usage, but i guess it can't be wrong to think about that since the data is send across the internet. I don't want to use up unnecessary traffic of the users traffic.
How would you read the rgba value out of that integer then?

Comment: @SebastianWeiß Unless your town has tens of millions of people, I doubt that the format you use to store your colors will make much difference. I've edited the answer to provide an example of getting a color out.

Comment: Really like your answer :) Thank you! I understand that the difference is very minor, but if there is a efficient way, why not use it? :)